# Drop duplicates across different groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with columns `name`, `ID`, `start`, `Code1`, `City`, `Real Start`. Jack has an ID with different `start`, those `start` have a `Code1` and `City` with a `Real Start`.
For the first `start==24/3/2022` with `ID==111` he starts with four `Code1`, then for the second `start==28/3/2022` he has 2 `Code1` because `start>=Real start` and finally he has one `Code`.

The idea: drop duplicates considering `Name` and `ID`  as they appear `Code1`.

[image]

```
data = tibble::tribble(
   ~Name,  ~ID,      ~Start, ~Code1,   ~City, ~Real.Start,
  "Jack", 111L, "24/3/2022",  "abc", "City1",  "8/4/2022",
  "Jack", 111L, "24/3/2022",  "def", "City2", "25/3/2022",
  "Jack", 111L, "24/3/2022",  "efg", "City3", "26/3/2022",
  "Jack", 111L, "24/3/2022",  "hij", "City4", "28/3/2022",
  "Jack", 222L, "28/3/2022",  "abc", "City1",  "8/4/2022",
  "Jack", 222L, "28/3/2022",  "hij", "City4", "28/3/2022",
  "Jack", 333L, "31/3/2022",  "abc", "City1",  "8/4/2022"
  )


output = tibble::tribble(
            ~Name,  ~ID,      ~Start, ~Code1,   ~City, ~Real.Start,
           "Jack", 111L, "24/3/2022",  "def", "City2", "25/3/2022",
           "Jack", 111L, "24/3/2022",  "efg", "City3", "26/3/2022",
           "Jack", 222L, "28/3/2022",  "hij", "City4", "28/3/2022",
           "Jack", 333L, "31/3/2022",  "abc", "City1",  "8/4/2022"
           )
```

Comment: The logic is not clear to me. What "date range"?

Comment: Well, it would just be dropping duplicates between groups.

Comment: There are no duplicates in the groups if using just `Name`, `ID`, and `Code1` (for instance, see `dplyr::distinct(data, Name, ID, Code1, .keep_all = TRUE)`). Your question suggests there should be some inequality test on one  or both of the date columns, however (1) you haven't explained what range is needed; and (2) your date columns are just strings, they should likely be `Date`-class objects (you likely need `mutate(across(c(Start, Real.Start), ~ as.Date(.x, format = "%d/%m/%Y")))`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You description is unclear, but I made a guess from the table you provided.

```
#first convert starts to date
data$Start%<>%as.Date(data$Start, format='%d/%m/%Y')
data$Real.Start%<>%as.Date(data$Start, format='%d/%m/%Y')

#select rows of the most recent start by 'Name' and 'Code1'
data%>%
  group_by(Name,Code1)%>%
  filter(Start==max(Start))%>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Name     ID Start      Code1 City  Real.Start
  <chr> <int> <date>     <chr> <chr> <date>    
1 Jack    111 2022-03-24 def   City2 2022-03-25
2 Jack    111 2022-03-24 efg   City3 2022-03-26
3 Jack    222 2022-03-28 hij   City4 2022-03-28
4 Jack    333 2022-03-31 abc   City1 2022-04-08
```

Comment: Or using the shorthand `slice_max(data, Start, by = c(Name, Code1))`